# Loop through SELECTED sheets (set activewindow.selected sheets)

Tags: vba, excel

My objective is to execute VBA code in selected sheets only.

I tried the following:

```
1    Sub selectedsheet()
2        Dim sh As Worksheet
3        Dim selectedshs As Worksheets
4        
5        Set selectedshs = ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
6        
7        For Each sh In selectedshs
8            MsgBox sh.Name
9        Next sh
10    End Sub
```

However in line 5, RunTime error 13 - Type Mismatch occurs.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try changing `Selectedshs` to a Sheets collection instead (there exists a sublte distinction between Worksheets and Sheets objects)

Comment: This worked. Merci!

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to declare your selectedshs as a generic Object.

```
Sub selectedsheet()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim selectedshs As Object

    Set selectedshs = ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets

    For Each sh In selectedshs
        MsgBox sh.Name
    Next sh
End Sub
```

or

```
Sub selectedsheet()
    Dim sh As WorkSheet

    For Each sh In ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets
        MsgBox sh.Name
    Next sh

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just use the count of the selected sheets (i.e. activewindow.SelectedSheets.count) and then cycle through those (i.e. activewindow.SelectedSheets(1).name) using an integer?

Comment: Apologies if I didn't include other parts of the code as it's pretty lengthy. I couldn't do this because right before I cycle through the selected sheets, I add a new sheet, thereby making the new sheet the only selected sheet. But thanks anyway!